# Why do I use ffmpeg to embed .ssa subtitles and ffprobe recognizes that the subtitle is ass format？

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I use ffmpeg to embed .ssa subtitles into mkv, but ffprobe recognizes that the subtitle is ass format.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i input.ssa -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c copy demo.mkv
```

Also, I learned that ssa subtitles also support MP4, but when I use the command to convert to MP4 that ffmpeg report error：could not find tag for codec ass in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
[image]
[enter link description here](http://www.mezzmo.com/wiki/doku.php?id=supported_subtitle_formats)

How can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 1):

Mp4 container needs you specify the subtitle codec to use.
Add : `-c:s mov_text`
Like that :
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -i input.ssa -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c copy -c:s mov_text demo.mp4`

Comment: Thank you for your help！It's worked. There is identified "subtitle: mov_text" by FFprobe,  but I need ssa subtitle.
If I use the code like that:
    ffmpeg -i input.avi -i input.ssa -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c copy -c:s ssa demo.mkv
An error reported that:
Subtitle codec 94212 is not supoorted

Comment: @mm_test As you asked to convert to mp4 and ssa subtitles are not supported by the mp4 container, I proposed a conversion to mov_text. If you want to keep the matroska (mkv) container, ssa subtitles are supported. Normally your last command is correct. Codec 94212 matches ssa well. Check your version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Should I change the version of ffmpeg for keeping the matroska (mkv) container, ssa subtitles are supported. When I enter ‘ffmpeg -version'，it's shown that:
ffmpeg version N-68994-g4df01d5 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers. Is it too old for Codec 94212?

Comment: @mm_test Your version is really very old. You would do well to update to benefit from bug fixes and improvements. There are releases for all platforms.

Comment: It's worked! There is another question. There is identified "subtitle: ass   metadata: encoder  Lavc60.4.110 ssa" by FFprobe. Why the format of subtitle is not ssa?

Comment: "ssa" stands for SubStation Alpha version 4.00 and "ass" stands for Advanced SubStation Alpha, the most advanced version 4.00+

Comment: I only need "ssa" stands. What can I do for this?